# Woocommerce digital product link issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need help with Woocommerce "Thank you" page.

After the user places an order, a page with thanks for the order and a link to download the product (e-book) is shown to him. An e-mail with the same link arrives at the same time.

Is it possible to define an option for the link to automatically download the file to the phone / computer and not open the file in the browser? This problem mainly affects mobile devices (e.g. Iphone with Safari). The file opens and the user has to click. options share -> save instead of force downloading.

In woocommerce products settings the option "Force download" is checked.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

There might be a filter for this, where you could add the attribute "download" to the anchor tag. I.e. `<a href="...." download>...</a>`, perhaps like this:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'filter_woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text( $text, $order ) {
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if ( $item->is_type( 'digital' ) ) {
            $text = str_replace( 'href=', 'download href=', $text );
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In which theme file should I add this filter ? I don't have so much experience with code snippets in WP. Have just created my page with pagebuilder.

Comment: Have added this snippet with Code snippet plugin, doesn't work :(